# How to access global variable in shared object(.so) from other C program?

Tags: c, linux

As title described, I'm trying to access global variable in .so from normal C program.

preload.h:

```cpp
int var;
void setting(int x);
```

test.c:

```cpp
#include "preload.h"
extern int var;
int main(){
 ... 
 setting(x);
 /* use var */

}
```

I expected `var` after setting is `x` but `var` still remain as 0.

compile:

```sh
gcc test.c -o test
gcc -shared -fPIC preload.c -o preload.so -ldl
```

execute:

```sh
LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/preload.so ./test
```

Comment: So what is in `preload.c`?

Comment: `int var;` in header file is a bad idea because it creates a variable whenever a file is compiled with the header is included and will lead to unintended creation of multiple instance of `var`.

Comment: You do not have access to "global" vars between programs, even if they are part of a library. You have to use OS depending mechanisms like shared memory to get access to data from different progs.

Comment: so is shared code, not shared data. You need to put shared data in shared memory.

Comment: @KamilCuk most stuff in `.c` is nothing to do with `var`, `setting` is simple assignment for `var`.

Comment: Oh, I miss it. `test.c` will use it. I'll update it.

Comment: never define variables in the .h file

Comment: @Steven `setting(var)` does not assign anything it just passes value of `var` to the function `settings`. `var` will not be changed

Comment: `var` in `preload.c` will be changed but I tried to make it also changed in `test.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code in your `test.c` ...

> ```
> extern int var;
> ```

... declares that there is an object of type `int` identified by the name `var` defined somewhere in the whole program.

This code in your `preload.h` ...

> ```
> void setting(int x);
> ```

... constitutes exactly such a definition as the other declaration promises, and it appears in every translation unit that includes the header, including that of `test.c`.  That makes the declaration in `test.c` redundant, but C allows that.  It also means that program `test` provides its own object `var`.

If your `preload.c` also includes `preload.h` then it also contains a definition of `var`.  If you combine these two translation units into a single program then you violate C's express prohibition against one program containing more than one external definition of the same identifier.  Undefined behavior results, and what you actually observe is a mild case.

The correct way to enable your `main()` function to use the same `var` object as your `setting()` function is

1. Make the declaration of `var` in `preload.h` explicitly `extern`:

   ```
   extern int var;
   ```

   In conjunction with that declaration not including an initializer, that causes the declaration to not serve as a definition.  This form is always what you want to use in header files.
2. Put a definition of `var` at file scope in `preload.c` (or in whatever translation unit should be considered to own that variable):

   ```
   int var;
   ```
3. (Optional) Remove the redundant declaration of `var` from `test.c`.

Note well, however, that that enables sharing `var` among different parts of *one* program, including functions in libraries, shared or static.  Based on your examples, I take that to be what you mean by "from other C program".  If, on the other hand, you mean you want to share data across separate programs, then putting external objects into shared libraries will not achieve that.  Each instance of each program using such a shared library will still get its own copy of those objects.

If in fact want to share data across programs then you will need to engage an OS-specific mechanism for that.  Linux has two flavors of shared memory, the System V flavor and the POSIX flavor.  I would recommend the latter.  Details of how to use it would be a whole other answer, however, and one which you can already find multiple times over both here on StackOverflow and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

IMO if you need to get some object from the share library, the cleanest way is to have "getters and setters"

```
int x;

x = getx();  // getter defined in shared library
/* do something */
setx(x); //setter defined in the shared library
```